# How do I go about selecting from a list and using the object in the list as a label?

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to use a randomly chosen string from a list and use the string as a label in my GUI.

I put the randomly chosen string into a separate list and to test it I printed it to see if it works and it does. Now I'm trying to use the chosen string in the second list as a label however it simply is not displaying it as a label. How would I go about coding the randomly chosen string to be shown as a label? Here is my code below:

```
class PquizB(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent, controller):

       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.grid()
       global Text
       write = ""
       var = len(Text)
       write = str(var)

       label = ttk.Label(self, text=write, font=MED_FONT)
       label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

I expected the label to display as the chosen string in the list however it prints out a 0 instead, at the grid position that it's supposed to be. I know that the string is in the list "Global Text" as I tested for its existence in the previous class.

Comment: Did you try printing `Text` and `var` out just before your label?

Comment: *"it prints out a 0 instead"*: This means your `list Text` is **empty**.

Comment: As I said, I tested it in the previous class by printing out Text and it prints out the chosen string which is the intended result. That is how I know that my list is not empty. I went as far as testing by appending the Text list into a separate text file to see if it makes anything and it did.

Comment: *"I know that my list is not empty."*: What gives the output of the suggestion from @ HenryYik?

Comment: Are you sure you have filled the list `Text` before creating the instance of `PquizB` class?

Comment: In the previous class, I fill the text in by using the random function to randomly select the string from "List"